# Why using Telnet with SNMP?

Tags: networking, snmp

Recently I got a question asking what is the reason to use SNMP in combination with telnet since using 2 protocols is not a good practice.

I did a research on the topic but could not find reasonable answer.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a bit of context? As is your question is really unclear. Telnet is very  insecure (it transmits passwords in clear text) and should not be used at all.

Comment: Your question is about two application-layer protocols which are off-topic here. Generally, both applications are very different, so different protocols are required.

Comment: @Zac67 I would argue that SNMP is totally on-topic here.

Comment: @JFL The use of SNMP in on-topic devices is definitely on-topic here, but not the protocol by itself. Or is it?

Comment: @Zac67 it seems obvious to me that a Network Management protocol is on-topic. It can be classified under "tools used by network professionals" or even better "design or theory of protocols used to operate a network" (from the [Asking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page)

Comment: @JFL I beg to differ - SNMP is not an "essential" network operating protocol like the ones listed on that page. Maybe one of the moderators can enlighten us.

Comment: I would agree SNMP is on topic, but the question was closed for being unclear.  The premise of the question is just wrong "2 protocols not a good practice", and it also invites opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an answer based on **SMTP** protocol, since it's more common to use **Telnet** to test **SMTP**, and since Telnet connects on a **TCP** port, rather than a **UDP** port like **SNMP**. I find myself sometimes confusing SMTP and SNMP.

People and tutorials tend to use basic SMTP commands via Telnet because common Windows user builds don't have a native application to support SMTP (and SNMP also). You would have to download some kind of app, and generally, if you just need to test quickly, especially to debug, just Telnet over TCP port 25 (or other port your service is established) can do that trick for you, since it's a client-server exchange message protocol.

Think of Telnet as the HyperTerminal application, that does serial and networked communications via a send-response terminal.